# Using an iterator to iterate through a LinkedList forwards then backwards

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator, iteration

I was able to make an iterator that prints the object contents of my linked list forwards.

```
Iterator<Object> Myiterator = MylinkedList.iterator();

        while(Myiterator.hasNext()){

            System.out.print(Myiterator.next() + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println();
```

How can I do this backwards? I would like it to not print in forward order, only iterate forward without printing then print backwards.

Comment: Looks like you need to use a ListIterator rather than a plain Iterator.

Comment: *or*, `Collections.reverse(MylinkedList);`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm looking to specifically use a plain iterator not a `ListIterator`

Comment: Then use @ElliottFrisch's suggestion

Comment: ***or***, push all of the elements into a `Deque` and then iterate that.

Comment: Is it possible to make a normal iterator that that go both forwards and backwards? Or is a `ListIterator` the only way?

Comment: @Blaise: that's why Java gives us the ListIterator, to allow us to do things that Iterator can't. So to answer your question, no, it's not possible. But don't take my word on this -- please check out the Iterator API and see -- does it have a `.previous()`  method? It has a `.next()` and `.hasNext()` to be sure, but does it have the equivalent for previous? Now check the ListIterator API and compare the two.